# What is the maximum value for STRING ordering in SQL (SQLite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database and I want to order my results by ascending order of a String column (`name`). I want the `null`-valued rows to be last in ascending order.

Moreover, I am doing some filtering on the same column (`WHERE name>"previously obtained value"`), which filters out the `NULL`-valued rows, which I do not want. Plus, the version of SQLite I'm using (I don't have control over this) does not support `NULLS LAST`. Therefore, to keep it simple I want to use `IFNULL(name,"Something")` in my `ORDER BY` and my comparison.

I want this `"Something"` to be as large as possible, so that my `null`-valued rows are always last. I have texts in Japanese and Korean, so I can't just use `"ZZZ"`.

Therefore, I see two possible solutions. First, use the "maximum" character used by SQLite in the default ordering of strings, do you know what this value is or how to obtain it? Second, as the cells can contain any type in SQLite, is there a value of any other type that will always be considered larger than any string?

**Example:**

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+
| id |      name       |   othercol    |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
|  1 |    English name | hello         |
|  2 |    NULL         | hi            |
|  3 |    NULL         | hi hello      |
|  4 |    暴鬼          | hola          |
|  5 |    NULL         | bonjour hello |
|  6 |    아바키        | hello bye     |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
```

Current request: 
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE othercol LIKE "hello" AND (name,id)>("English name",1) ORDER BY (name,id)`

Result (by ids): 6

Problems: NULL names are filtered out because of the comparison, and when I have no comparison they are shown first.

What I think would solve these problems:
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE othercol LIKE "hello" AND (IFNULL(name,"Something"),id)>("English name",1) ORDER BY (IFNULL(name,"Something"),id)`

But I need `"Something"` to be larger than any string I might encounter.

Expected result: 6, 3, 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, for anyone looking for a character larger than any other (when I'm posting this, the unicode table might get expanded), here's your guy:
`CAST(x'f48083bf' AS TEXT)`.

Example in my case:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE othercol LIKE "hello" AND (IFNULL(name,CAST(x'f48083bf' AS TEXT)),id)>("English name",1) ORDER BY (IFNULL(name,CAST(x'f48083bf' AS TEXT)),id)`

Answer (score 4):

I think a simpler way is to use [`nulls last`](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/ordering-term.html):

```
order by column nulls last
```

This works with both ascending and descending sorts.  And it has the advantage that it can make use of an index on the column, which `coalesce()` would probably prevent.

Comment: @forpas . . . Can you explain why it is in the official documentation for the product, which is referenced in the answer?

Comment: SQLite 3.30 does support NULLS last.

Comment: I tried before asking but apparently the version I have access to does not support it, and don't have the control over which version I'm using.

Comment: @MaverickChardet . . . When you update your version of SQLite, remember `NULLS LAST`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE SOMECOL > "previously obtained value" OR SOMECOL IS NULL
```

so the `NULL`s are not filtered out (since you want them).
You can sort the `NULL`s last, like this:

```
ORDER BY SOMECOL IS NULL, SOMECOL
```

The expresssion:

```
SOMECOL IS NULL
```

evaluates to `1` (True) or `0` (False), so the values that are **not** `NULL` will be sorted first.
Edit
If you want a string that is greater than any `name` in the table, then you can get it by:

```
select max(name) || ' ' from mytable
```

so in your code use:

```
ifnull(name, (select max(name) || ' ' from mytable))
```

Comment: I saw this before asking the question, but it does not work because I also use `WHEN SOMECOL>value`, which automatically filters out the `NULL`s. So I really need to consider some value replacing `NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works either because I am doing my ordering on multiple columns, to always have a total order. In my original post I simplified things because I thought saying I want to do it with IFNULL would be enough to not get alternative answers.
I have edited my original post with more details and an example. Sorry for being originally too vague.

Comment: `WHERE name LIKE ? AND (IFNULL(name,"Something"),id)>(?,?)` would not work beacusw NULLs would be filtered out by the LIKE operator since it is followed by AND. So first clarify what you want by posting expected results for  sample data that would cover all possible cases, or else your requirement is unclear.

Comment: I made a mistake, my LIKE is done on another column. Anyway I have added values and result + expected result to my example.

Comment: What is the need for `AND (name,id)>("English name","hi hello")` do? And is it really **id** or **othercol**?

Comment: This is used for pagination, I don't want to load everything at once so `AND (name,id)>("English name", 1)` is here basically as a more efficient `OFFSET`, because I know that my rows are ordered by (name,id) I can simply use the values of the last row of the previous page. And it is actually `id`, `id` is only here so that I have a total ordering on my rows, and I know that they are unique.
EDIT: I had actually made a mistake, it was 1 and not "hi hello" (fixed in the example)

Comment: Thank you! I agree this works but I'd like to avoid making a subquery for the max, which has to browse the entire content of the table (I run this on a mobile phone). I could recompute it every time the database is modified, but there has to be a string which is larger than all others right? Something larger than latin characters, Japanese characters and Korean characters at least. Do you know if it is ordered by location in the UTF table?